# Can profiles be updated across parent/meta in the new beta sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta-phase, stackexchange-2.0

I've changed my profile information on Gaming, but the changes aren't reflected on Meta.

Currently, only reputation is updated from parent to Meta. Profile information is set in stone as it is, since there's no way to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please wait 1 hour for auto-sync, per the /faq on the child meta.

You can also log out and log back again if you absolutely, positively, must have your change take effect immediately.

Comment: These past 6 days have been the longest hour of my life, then.

Comment: Oh wow, logging in/out fixed it, thanks. However, I had changed my profile on Gaming several days ago and it never updated, so I don't know about the auto-sync.